# How to Tune Pipeline GridSearch wih SelectFromModel?

Tags: python, pipeline, gridsearchcv

I used a pipeline with a columnTransformer, and don't know how to fix and tune the GridSearch with the embeded classifier inside SelectFromModel?

```
num_df = X_train.select_dtypes(include=np.number).columns
# Numerical Preprocessing
num_pre = Pipeline(steps =
                   [("Num Imputer", SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')),
                    ("Scaler", preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()),
                    ("PCA", PCA(n_components = 0.95))])


cat_df = X_train.select_dtypes(exclude=np.number).columns
# Categorical Preprocessing
cat_pre = Pipeline(steps =
                   [("Cat Imputer", SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='most_frequent')),
                    ("onehot", OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore')),
               >>>>>("Categorical_Selector", SelectFromModel(ExtraTreesClassifier(n_estimators=100,
                                                                       criterion = 'entropy')))])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('num', num_pre, num_df),
        ('cat', cat_pre, cat_df)])

pipe = Pipeline(steps = 
                [('preprocessor', preprocessor),
                 #('UnderSampling', RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)),
                 ('RandomForest', RandomForestClassifier())])

pipe.fit(X_train, y_train)

param_grid = {'preprocessor__num__PCA__n_components': [0.99, 0.97, 0.95, 0.93],
        >>>>>>'preprocessor__cat__Categorical_Selector__ExtraTreesClassifier__n_estimators': [100, 200, 300],
              'RandomForest__bootstrap': [False],
              'RandomForest__criterion': ['entropy'],
              'RandomForest__max_depth': range(100, 300, 100),
              'RandomForest__max_features': ['auto'],
              'RandomForest__min_samples_leaf': [1, 3],
              'RandomForest__min_samples_split': range(1, 10, 2),
              'RandomForest__n_estimators': range(200, 1000, 100)
             }

grid_search = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                           scoring="roc_auc",
                           param_grid= param_grid,
                           cv=2,
                           verbose = 1,
                           n_jobs = -1
                          )

grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I tried to tune hyperparameters via pipeline GridSearch and get this error:

```
ValueError: Invalid parameter ExtraTreesClassifier for estimator SelectFromModel(estimator=ExtraTreesClassifier(criterion='entropy')). Check the list of available parameters with `estimator.get_params().keys()`.
```